# To Delete a div if images from A to B in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This Is the My Html Code

```
<div class="ui-grid-a" class="checkpoint" style="width: 100%; background #F4F4F4; height: 3em;" id="two">
  <div class="ui-block-a" align="left" id="imgch2" style="width:20%">
    <img src="../images/checkpoint3.svg" id="check2" style="height: 1em; width: 50%; padding-top:0.7em;">
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-b" align="center">
    <span style="font-size: 13px; font-family: MyriadPro-Regular; color: #BD2929;">NickName8</span>
    <br>
    <span style="font-size: 10px; font-family: MyriadPro-Regular; color: C5C6C9;">Telephone-9800045303</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have several Divs with custom images. On click of that image it changes to another image ,say Image B. Then I have to write a function to remove that entire Div which contains that Image. I am a beginner In jquery. Please Help me out

```
$("#viewone").each(function() {
  var $this = $('img');
  if ($this.attr('src') == '../images/checkpoint4.svg')
    $($this).closest('.checkpoint').remove();
});
```

This is how far i have come with my jquery

Comment: I cant see viewone element in html

Comment: Try `var $this = $('img', this);` as I suppose you are about to target `img` in the `each` context..

Comment: _viewone_ is the id of the entire page. forgot to mention that

Comment: @Rayon Its not working

Comment: @sushant, Define _"not working"_

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through all images like this and remove checkpoint:

```
$('#viewone img').each(function () { // it finds all images in #viewone
    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.attr('src') == '../images/checkpoint4.svg')
    $this.closest('.checkpoint').remove(); // use $this instead of $($this)
});
```